# how to apply particular FORMAT of date by using eval?

Tags: asp.net

I have used following code :

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="Time" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_ON")%>'> </asp:HyperLink>
```

It will display the date in the format: 11/4/2010 10:52:33 AM

But I want it to display `11/4/2010`. How would I do this?

Comment: this is the code:<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_ON")%>'>
                                                    </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Please any one edit my code so that it will display on top.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_ON", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}")%>'> </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this -

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate1" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("CREATED_ON").ToString()).ToString("d") %>'> </asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

this should do the trick:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CREATED_ON", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a DateTime variable named MyDate:

```
DateTime MyDate;
```

If you want juste the date part:

```
MyDate.Value.ToString("d");
```

With the day:

```
MyDate.Value.ToString("D");
```

Here is a usefull doc [PDF Doc](http://www.google.be/#hl=fr&biw=1920&bih=881&q=msnet-formatting-strings&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=d4865a5248fa89dc)

Answer (score 1):

1. I Was Face Problem When Date Is NULL.
2. It Will Help Me When CREATED_ON Date Is Null.
3. Use This Code When You Are Not Sure That Your Date Is NULL OR NOT.

   ```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate1" runat="server" Text='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CREATED_ON").ToString())) ? "" : DateTime.Parse(Eval("CREATED_ON").ToString()).ToString("d") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try THis Also

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_ON", "{0:d}")%>'> </asp:HyperLink>
```