# show just the date when bind a datetime Field in label in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

i have a repeater in my asp.net page and bind a data source to this repeater
there is a label in this repeater and the text of label is a datetime field
i want that label only  show me the date not date and time

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostDate") %>'></asp:Label>
```

this code show date and time together

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223938/how-to-apply-particular-format-of-date-by-using-eval

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 

<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostDate") %>' DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `Eval` with format as below

```
Text='<%# Eval("PostDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
```