# Calendar Return

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I'm using a Calendar object on a GridView. Currently it works but when I want to update my row  I can't choose the return of my object.

On update it return to me `: MMM JJ YYYY HH:MM AM/PM -> avr 13 2014 12:00AM`
I just want a `JJ/MM/YYYY` format !

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Cal_date_debut" runat="server" SkinID="Calendar" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("date_debut_session") %>'></asp:Calendar>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_debut_session") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

There is the code to display my calendar.

Anyone see how to do that ?

Comment: The question is rather unclear, why can't you use [`Calendar.SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a `DateTime` instead of a `String`?

Comment: The dateTime format return things like MM/JJ/YYYY HH:MM:SS, it's the same :/ 
So my internship supervisor ask me to use String format for the date fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo) problem

try this

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Cal_date_debut" runat="server" SkinID="Calendar" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("date_debut_session") %>' VisibleDate='<%# Bind("date_debut_session") %>' >
                </asp:Calendar>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_debut_session", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

as you can see the `SelectedDate` is passe from the db (I guess) as a DateTime object, instead the `{0:d}` format string transform the DateTime from db into a string formatted like `dd/MM/yyyy`, but there are [other options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that.

From the codebehind you could get the same output by formatting the `Cal_date_debut.SelectedDate` like this

```
Cal_date_debut.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Notice the `VisibleDate` property, binded to `date_debut_session`.

I've tried to update the columns using a sqlDataSource and it worked.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm trying this now, for my query i'm using the "updateCommand" of my SqlDataSource, can I work on it in the code behind ?

Comment: Yes, but it's tricky, since datetime parsing in SQL is a pain in the neck.
I'm not very good at vb6, and I would do that from the aspx page by adding to the SqlDataSource an Update Command like `UPDATE [table] SET [date_debut_session] = @date_debut_session WHERE [id] = @id` and  asp:parameters.

Comment: The {0:d} solution didn't Work here :/

Comment: define 'here': in the aspx or in the codebehind? 'cause I've tried and it works in the aspx but I haven't tried in the codebehind.

Comment: In the Code Behind, in the aspx, after paste your code it does nothing, i still have things like this :
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/14/1396613407-sans-titre.jpg

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223938/how-to-apply-particular-format-of-date-by-using-eval)?

Comment: The format is now good, in my db, i'm using the type "String", because of my intershnip supervisor, but I replace them by a "Date" type and now, all works correctly ! Thanks !